ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS emacs can't find assoc
Just upgraded to 24.04.1 LTS, but my emacs configuration file can no longer load. Gives this error:
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, assoc
Seems lisp cannot find "assoc" any more. This worked just before upgrade from 22LTS.
GNU Emacs 29.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.41,
cairo version 1.18.0) of 2024-04-01, modified by Debian

uname -a
Linux BBalien 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


perhaps it got nuked in the upgrade? Uninstall and re-install perhaps.

you can also try to find the file on your system see this answer

If you want to find where the init file for an existing Emacs is located, from within Emacs itself, you can look at the value of the user-init-file variable with C-h v user-init-file RET  If it is nil then no init file is used. Emacs looks for your init file using the filenames ‘~/.emacs.el’, ‘~/.emacs’, or ‘~/.emacs.d/init.el’ in that order. Mine (24.04) is the second.

Uninstall and reinstall what? Which package is "assoc" contained in?

I have customized ~/.emacs for years, but now after upgrading to 24.04.1LTS, my ~/.emacs can't load because it can't find "assoc". Is that a lisp issue? An emacs issue?

I found that in recent emacs, assoc.el is obsolete, but I was loading tex-wcount.el which in turn require'ed assoc.el. Once solved this broken dependency, emacs loads without a problem.

My understanding is that assoc was depreciated from emacs 24.2. Ubuntu 24.04 is installing emacs –
GNU Emacs 29.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.41, cairo version 1.18.0) of 2024-04-01, modified by Debian

You can search your startup files for this with the following script: -
 find ~/.emacs.d -name "*.el" -exec grep -H "(require 'assoc)" {} \;

The following link, I think (but I am no expert), suggests a solution.
https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/242

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/assoc-deprecated
I hope this was of some help
